# C# LINQ to XML - How to write specific XElements to file

Tags: c#, xml

I was wondering how i can write a specific section of an XDocument to file.

Suppose I load the entire document when my application starts up, and then read settings using application load. When I modify a property of my class, I wish to write JUST THAT PROPERTY (or just that property and its children) back to the file, **leaving unchanged any other modification to the XDocument (in memory)**

My current code look like the following (note I have some wrappers around the XDocument and XElement classes):

```
    public void SaveRecursiveData()
    {
        //Load the original file into a new document
        XmlConfig tmp = new XmlConfig(_XmlDoc.Filename,false);

        //find the node i am interested in
        XElement currentElement = tmp.Xmldoc.XPathSelectElement(this.Path);

        //Replace it with my IN MEMORY one
        currentElement.ReplaceWith(_XmlNode);

        //Write the whole temporary document back to the file 
        tmp.Save(); 
    }
```

Is this the best approach or is there another way?

Comment: did you make some research before you posting question here?

3-rd link in google with fraze `xml linq tutorial` is `http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/08/linq-to-xml-tutorial/`

Comment: Yes I have done some research, and unfortunately, the link you provided doesn't solve my problem. The key here is the phrase "Leaving unchanged any other modification to the XDocument in memory"

Answer (score -1):

You can just do

```
currentElement.Attribute("toChange").Value = "mynewvalue";
```

instead of `ReplaceWith`